# jQuery radio subcategory uncheck on parent button change

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, button

I have a form that finds lost and found items.

```
<input type="radio" name="subcatitemlost" value="subDiv1" />Luggage
<div id="subDiv1" class="desc">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="subluggage" id="truck" value="t" />
    </label>Trunk</br>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="subluggage" id="chest" value="chest" />
    </label>Chest</br>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="subluggage" id="suitcase" value="suitcase" />
    </label>Suitcase</br>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="subluggage" id="duffelbag" value="duffelbag" />
    </label>Duffelbag</br>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="subluggage" id="tote" value="tote" />
    </label>Tote</br>
</div>
<br />

<input type="radio" name="subcatitemlost" value="subDiv2" />Clothing
<div id="subDiv2" class="desc">
    <input type="radio" name="subclothing" id="shirt" value="shirt" />
    </label>Shirt</br>
    <input type="radio" name="subclothing" id="shoes" value="shoes" />
    </label>Shoes</br>
    <input type="radio" name="subclothing" id="pants" value="pants" />
    </label>Pants</br>
    <input type="radio" name="subclothing" id="jacket" value="jacket" />
    </label>Jacket</br>
    <input type="radio" name="subclothing" id="suit" value="suit" />
    </label>Suit</br>
    <input type="radio" name="subclothing" id="hat" value="hat" />
    </label>Hat</br>
</div>
<br />
```

The main categories will unselect themselves upon selection of another main category , however , the subcategories will remain selected and I cannot figure how to control that.I am looking for the script that doesn't allow another subcategory to be selected when the correct button is selected.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div.desc").hide();
    $("input[name$='subcatitemlost']").click(function () {
        var test = $(this).val();
        $("div.desc").hide();
        $("#" + test).show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div.desc").hide();
    $("input[name$='subcatitemlost']").click(function() {
        var test = $(this).val();
        $("div.desc").hide();
        $("#" + test).show();
        $("div input:radio").attr('checked', false);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dbtA4/